# I'm not able to debug Laravel project using Xdebug on VSCode

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I'm trying to step-by-step debug my new Laravel project using Xdebug (PHP Debug extension for VSCode) breakpoints as I usually do but I can't make Xdebug work as supposed to.

I'm trying to call some basic CRUD APIs. At first I tried taking some configuration entries from various answers online, this is my current configuration:

xdebug.ini

```ini
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1

xdebug.client_host = localhost
xdebug.client_port = 9003
xdebug.log = /tmp/xdebug_remote.log
xdebug.log_level = 7
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
```

launch.json

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "log": true,
            "port": 9003
        }
    ]
}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is Xdebug working fine intercepting my requests so that I can have breakpoints and step-by-step debugging working.

I'm trying calling the APIs using Thunder Client for VSCode, `curl` command on terminal and by browsing to them using Chrome: every API is reachable and working but not debugging.

I see Xdebug starting running correctly, using `log: true` I see no errors in VSCode output but I don't see any request incoming either, as if Xdebug isn't intercepting nor seeing any request coming from my Laravel application.

I run my application using in-built `php artisan serve` command on `localhost:8000`. The debugger is running using PHP Debug extension for VSCode.

I'm on a Debian machine running PHP 8.2.4 and Laravel version is 10.5.1.

I'm not using any containerization or virtualization structure such as Docker or Vagrant or anything similar.

Comment: 1) What Xdebug log has to say? Not VSCode one, the actual Xdebug one. 2) Please provide your live/actual Xdebug config -- an output of `xdebug_info()` captured in a same way as you are trying to debug (make some new API endpoint and call it there). **P.S.** `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` -- that's Xdebug v2. I does nothing in v3 (as it was renamed to `xdebug.start_with_request`).

Comment: 3) When you run your `Listen for Xdebug` config in VSCode -- do you see it listening on TCP 9003 port (`netstat` or whatever command you have got there on Debian to see the current network connections)?

Comment: I figured out I was writing configuration to an '.ini' file with a typo in it so it didn't apply. I remove xdebug.remote_autostart = 1 after that and then now it seems to be working as expected. Thank you for your help.